# How to hang up on incoming call when I am already on a call?

Tags: iphone, call

How do i hang up on incoming call? there seems to be no option but to hang up on current call also.  If i let it ring it keeps buzzing which is very annoying

Answer (score 1):

You can press the volume down button on the side of the phone to mute the ringing of the incoming call without having to interrupt your current call.